# Opening port not working

Tags: networking, python, curl, ufw, port

I have a python server running on port 8000 on a raspberry pi and would like to make it accessible within the local network, which is currently not working.

The interface wlan0 is configured with the IP 10.0.0.69 and netmask 255.255.255.0.

I can't reach the server within the local network (from a different host):

```
root@DESKTOP-Lukas:~# curl http://10.0.0.69:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.0.69 port 8000: Connection refused
```

I also can't reach the server from the raspberry pi:

```
lukas@raspberrypi:~ $ curl http://10.0.0.69:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.0.69 port 8000: Connection refused
```

The server is running and listening on port 8000:

```
lukas@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo netstat -tnlp | ack 8000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      743/python
```

The server responds properly when using localhost:

```
lukas@raspberrypi:~ $ curl localhost:8000
<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL / was not found on this server.</p>
```

The firewall has allow actions for port 8000:

```
lukas@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
...
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: You are not listening external inerface. You are listening (bound) to 172.0.0.1 (localhost). See "Local Address"  column

Comment: Who is the troll downvoting all questions here?

Comment: Sadly, it's unlikely they will reveal themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `netstat` output shows you the problem:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      743/python
```

Specifically, `127.0.0.1:8000` shows that your web server is bound only to the loopback address `127.0.0.1`.  You need to either bind it to the actual network interface or, more simply, bind it to all addresses (usually by specifying `0.0.0.0`) and it will then be accessible by all other hosts with a route to your Pi.